# Can send a message using the Telegram API via. the browser but not a python script

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I can send a message to a telegram channel that includes my own bot using the following url in a browser:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot*****/sendMessage?chat_id=-********&text=Hello%20World! #there's a - before the chat id value
```

However, the following python code:

```
import telebot

API_TOKEN = '*********'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)
chat_id='-*******'

try:
    text_telegram='testing'
    print('line1')  
    print(bot.send_message(chat_id, text_telegram))
    print('line2')  
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Returns:

```
{'ok': False, 'error': 'Got unexpected response. (404) - {"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}'}
```

UPDATE:

So running the following commands resolved my issue. Can someone please explain why I had to run this and what's the reason for the last line? Surely the third line installs the latest version?

```
pip3 uninstall telebot
pip3 uninstall PyTelegramBotAPI
pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI
pip3 install --upgrade pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you used the tele_bot package, which is not the offical one thus probably bugged and not working.
So your fix removed the bad package (`pip3 uninstall...`), and the following lines installed the aproporaite (offical) package.

Assuming you uninstalled PyTelegramBotAPI, reinstalling should have bee sufficent. If you hadn't uninstalled it, updating (line 4) is a good idea.

Side note: You supplied the tele_bot package with your private API keys, I haven't examined that package, but it could be malicous and stole you API token. So I would recommend invalidating the old API token and generating a new one.